# cakephp211 conditions issues

Tags: cakephp-2.0

greatings!
my models are not being configured as containable. this following query dont display the correct result (i want to retrieve all the available cars between two dates in all category)

```
$car=$this->Genre->find('all', array(
                            'contain' => array(
                                'cars'=>array(
                                    'conditions'=>array(
                                        'cars.startdate <=' => $qdu ,
                                        'cars.enddate >=' => $qau
                                    )
                                )
                            )
                        )
                    );
```

this is my Genre model:

```
class Genre extends AppModel {
       public $actsAs = array('Containable');

    public $belongsTo = array(
    'houses' => array(
        'className' => 'houses',
        'foreignKey' => 'houses_id',
        'conditions' => '',
        'fields' => '',
        'order' => ''
    )
);

public $hasMany = array(
    'cars' => array(
        'className' => 'cars',
        'foreignKey' => 'genres_id',
        'dependent' => false,
        'conditions' => '',
        'fields' => '',
        'order' => '',
        'limit' => '',
        'offset' => '',
        'exclusive' => '',
        'finderQuery' => '',
        'counterQuery' => ''
    )
);
```

}

and this is car model:

```
class Car extends AppModel {

    public $belongsTo = array(
    'Genres' => array(
        'className' => 'Genres',
        'foreignKey' => 'genres_id',
        'conditions' => '',
        'fields' => '',
        'order' => ''
    )
);

public $hasMany = array(
    'ways' => array(
        'className' => 'ways',
        'foreignKey' => 'cars_id',
        'dependent' => false,
        'conditions' => '',
        'fields' => '',
        'order' => '',
        'limit' => '',
        'offset' => '',
        'exclusive' => '',
        'finderQuery' => '',
        'counterQuery' => ''
    )
);
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Model names should normally be singular, so "Car" instead of "cars".

```
$car=$this->Genre->find('all', array(
                            'contain' => array(
                                'Car'=>array(
                                    'conditions'=>array(
                                        'Car.startdate <=' => $qdu ,
                                        'Car.enddate >=' => $qau
                                    )
                                )
                            )
                        )
                    );
```

Also, make sure the Genre model loads the Containable behaviour.

```
class Genre extends AppModel {
   $actsAs = array('Containable');
}
```

Associations should also use singular, capitalised model names:

```
class Genre extends AppModel {
  public $actsAs = array('Containable');

  public $belongsTo = array(
    'House' => array(
        'className' => 'House',
        'foreignKey' => 'houses_id',
        'conditions' => '',
        'fields' => '',
        'order' => ''
    )
  );

  public $hasMany = array(
    'Car' => array(
        'className' => 'Car',
        'foreignKey' => 'genres_id',
        'dependent' => false,
        'conditions' => '',
        'fields' => '',
        'order' => '',
        'limit' => '',
        'offset' => '',
        'exclusive' => '',
        'finderQuery' => '',
        'counterQuery' => ''
    )
  );
}
```

It's a Cake convention to have pluralised controllers (CarsController, GenresController) and singular models (Car, Genre). When defining associations you're in essence linking models together and not controllers, hence the need for singular, capitalised classnames.

Comment: before, i retrieved all data (unwanted too). now doing so, i have an error: Warning (512): Model "Genre" is not associated with model "Car" [CORE\Cake\Model\Behavior\ContainableBehavior.php, line 339]

Comment: That means there is no association set up for the Genre model. You probably want a `hasMany` relationship as a Genre can have multiple Cars. See the manual for more information: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html

Comment: ok mensch thanks! but i set a hasmany relationship to genre model and i have the same error

Comment: Could you update your question with the code of the Genre and Car model?

Comment: I've updated my answer with some pointers regarding associations.

Comment: greats thanks mensch! my problem is solved! but now i want to retieve data between more than two tables. more explain: i get this error when i need to retrieve data from table 'car' and table 'house': Warning (512): Model "house" is not associated with model "car" [CORE\Cake\Model\Behavior\ContainableBehavior.php, line 339]! in fact table genre is between table car and table house like this: house has many genre,   genre has many car...  thanks for your comments

Comment: That's because there's no direct association with House defined in the Car model. I'm not sure how you've constructed the Containable array in the find method and where you're calling it exactly, in the CarsController? You could updated your question but it goes a bit beyond the scope of what you were originally asking.